Possible to upload/sync 500GB worth of files to remote storage in under a week?
Setup: rclone & rsync newbie (I do read and have frequently consulted the docs). rclone & rsync installed on local client (MacBook Pro on 10.14.6) Remote server is a 2TB "storage box" on AlphaVPS: x86-64 running Debian 12.
Task: Copy music files (.flac and .aiff) from my Mac to the remote. Some folders start with hyphen or underscore character (e.g. _Recordings, -Classical…), and many files contain special characters (e.g. é, ù, ä, etc. -- files are mostly classical music ).
Problem:
First attempts at rsync on the command line were a nonstarter, as rsync appeared not to be able to handle directories that started with - or _. I'm not asserting that rsync can't do that; only that apparently I can't do that with rsync. I promptly moved on to rclone.
I configured my remote storage in rclone.
I've tried rclone mount with --vfs-cache set both to full and off. With vsf-cache full the cache racked up half a terrabyte, b/c write-backs to the remote executed at glacial speed (we're talking scant MB/hour), and my 1TB root SSD threw No more room at the Inn! warnings, despite --vfs-cache-max setting of 50GB.
(Fast-forward 24 hours of obsessive research and tinkering.)
I'm currently running this command: rclone copy *local-path* *remote-path* --transfers=60 -P -- and the ETA has been ranging between 48+ hours and ETA 6d13h51m, most recently settling on 6+ days.
(Before this, I've tried several variations on this theme: rclone copy /Volumes/MyWhitePlume4TB/Music\ of\ the\ Spheres/_Recordings-To-Go\ \(Logopolis\) OPortumnus:/home/mark/Music-of-the-Spheres/_Recordings-To-Go --modify-window 2s --sftp-disable-hashcheck=true --sftp-chunk-size 32k --sftp-concurrency 512 --transfers=8 -P --log-file=/Volumes/MyWhitePlume4TB/__rclone/session.log --log-level INFO. -- Which specific variations, exhaustion prevents me from enumerating.)
If this is the best I can hope for, I can live with that. I have already consulted https://forum.rclone.org/t/rclone-mount-vfs-cache-mode-full-slower-than-none-why/36505 and https://forum.rclone.org/t/rclones-sftp-is-substantially-slower-150-than-an-sshfs-mount-or-the-oss-sftp-implementation/38034 -- and probably other forum threads.
Does anyone have a better idea -- and I mean any method -- than I've been able to find?
